# Using SQL like and % in Perl

Tags: sql, perl

When I use the following code, I only seem to print the last results from my array. I think it has something to do with my like clause and the % sign. Any ideas?

```
my @keywords = <IN>;
my @number = <IN2>;

foreach my $keywords (@keywords)
{
  chomp $keywords;

  my $query = "select *
    from table1 a, table2 b
    where a.offer = b.offer
    and a.number not in (@number)
    and a.title like ('%$keywords%')";

  print $query."\n";

  my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query)
    or die ("Error: Could not prepare sql statement on $server : $sth\n" .
            "Error: $DBI::errstr\n");

   $sth->execute
     or die ("Error: Could not execute sql statement on $server : $sth\n" .
             "Error: $DBI::errstr\n");

  while (my @results = $sth->fetchrow_array())
  {
    print OUT "$results[0]\t$results[1]\t$results[2]\t$results[3]\t",
              "$results[4]\t$results[5]\t$results[6]\t$results[7]\t",
              "$results[8]\n";          
  }
}

close (OUT);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate you question ?

Comment: When I run the above query in perl I only seem to get the results printed from the last keyword in the file I am reading in. When I print the query to the screen, the end part of %' replaces the an of and. So it looks like %'d a.title like '%football shirt

Comment: Never, never, never interpolate user-input into a database query. never. `DBI` gives you bind values. Use them!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300012/perl-dbi-with-sql-statement-with-a-like-condition?rq=1. Please use the link more description are given related to your question

Comment: Someone should teach you prepare: http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#prepare

Comment: Quote your SQL code with `q(select * from foo)`. This makes it possible to use single (string) and double (identifier) quotes for the SQL code.

Comment: If you want to use bind values and don't know ahead of time how many values will be in `@number`, the expression `join ',' ('?') x @number` may provide some inspiration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your `IN` file was created on a Windows system, so has CRLF sequences (roughly `\r\n`) between the lines, but that you're running this script on a *nix system (or in Cygwin or whatnot). So this line:

```
    chomp $keywords;
```

will remove the trailing `\n`, but not the `\r` before it. So you have a stray carriage-return inside your `LIKE` expression, and no rows match it.

If my guess is right, then you would fix it by changing the above line to this:

```
    $keywords =~ s/\r?\n?\z//;
```

to remove any carriage-return *and/or* newline from the end of the line.

(You should also make the changes that innaM suggests above, using bind variables instead of interpolating your values directly into the query. But that change is orthogonal to this one.)

Comment: It was exactly that @ruakh. Thanks for the tip. I will also look into using the bind variables.

Answer (score 0):

Show the output of the `print $query` and maybe we can help you.  Better yet, show the output of:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;
print Dumper($query);
```

Until then, your comment about "replaces the an of and" makes me think your input has carriage returns, and the use of @number is unlikely to work if there's more than one.